# Conversion using Buffer is different from base64.fromArrayBuffer(). Why does that happen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, arraybuffer

TempId looks like this:
`new Uint8Array([1, 252, 232, 40, 235, 180, 121, 67, 150, 7, 110, 99, 195, 156, 150, 82, 131, 163, 84, 209, 102, 76, 175, 209, 33, 104, 1, 251, 127, 70, 88, 178, 57, 216, 48, 202, 161, 248, 243, 170, 190, 126, 39, 111, 231, 116, 69, 133, 183, 59, 54, 1, 193, 110, 191, 48, 235, 14, 172, 162, 213, 181, 147, 83, 90])`

**`Buffer.from(tempId).toString('base64');`** returns this:
`AfzoKOu0eUOWB25jw5yWUoOjVNFmTK/RIWgB+39GWLI52DDKofjzqr5+J2/ndEWFtzs2AcFuvzDrDqyi1bWTU1o=`

CredId looks like this:

`new Uint8Array([1, 252, 232, 40, 235, 180, 121, 67, 150, 7, 110, 99, 195, 156, 150, 82, 131, 163, 84, 209, 102, 76, 175, 209, 33, 104, 1, 251, 127, 70, 88, 178, 57, 216, 48, 202, 161, 248, 243, 170, 190, 126, 39, 111, 231, 116, 69, 133, 183, 59, 54, 1, 193, 110, 191, 48, 235, 14, 172, 162, 213, 181, 147, 83, 90])`

**`base64.fromArrayBuffer(credId, true);`** returns this:

`AfzoKOu0eUOWB25jw5yWUoOjVNFmTK_RIWgB-39GWLI52DDKofjzqr5-J2_ndEWFtzs2AcFuvzDrDqyi1bWTU1o`

As you can see, the token are very similar, but there are a couple of differences ('=' at the end, '/' instead of '_', and '-' instead of '+'.
Why does that happen?

Comment: The second version is a URL friendly base64,   `/+=` are not goood to put into URL's..  More info here -> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. How would I reach the second version using the input?

Comment: You could just replace the `/` with `_`, `+` with `-`, and drop the padding `=`, but do bear in mind the second version is not as well supported.  eg,  Javascript's `btoa` will not handle the second form.

Comment: Are those changes going to be consistent? Like can I assume that every "/" should be replaced with "_", etc? This is a randomly generated token, so I don't want to hard code conversions.

Comment: Looking at the spec I linked, it looks pretty consistent yeah..